# Remove "Submitted by [user] on [date]" from content shown on a Views page

Tags: views

How does one remove the "Submitted by [user] on [date]" bit from content shown on a Views page?

I am assuming it is to remove some php code, but unsure what php file the code lives in. (I tried node.tpl.php)

I am using Drupal 7 Bartik theme.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Administration > Structure > Content Types. Find the content type on which you want to disable author information, click edit. At the bottom of the edit page you'll click on "Display settings" and uncheck "Display author and date information".

This will disable the display of author info for all content view modes, but you will still be able to pull out this info when constructing a View via Views module if you need to.